# How to retrieve all images from sql to the html DIV tag using php?

Tags: php

I want to show all images from sql to my webpage.All images will come But the only
thing is it will not show every image separately.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("buy") or die(mysql_error());
$get = "Select * from hibuy";
$get2 = mysql_query($get);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($get2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo "<div >";
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>";  // Here This is not Working
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but I do know that header shouldn't be there.

Comment: actually i want to retrieve all images from my database and display all of them into a page.all images are comming but the problem is they are not shown separate.the only image is the last image showing.

Comment: I think you should remove the header you are not sending raw data. What does the image column contain in your database ? A path or base64 data ?

Comment: It's best not to store images inside the database, just store them in a webfolder, and in your DB just use a pointer (filename) and point to the image, this is must faster and keeps your DB small & neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is "a bit unorthodox", but this way it might work:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($get2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $imageData = base64_encode($row['image']);

    // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
    $src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData;

    echo "<div >";
    echo "<img src='".$src."'>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Given, you have image data in your database, not the URL of the image.
In that case, just leave the header....

as seen here: http://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving an id to each one of the divs or style them for margin that is greater than or equal to the image width.Assuming you image width is 50px, this code shall work.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("buy") or die(mysql_error());
$get = "Select * from hibuy";
$get2 = mysql_query($get);
$i = 0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($get2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo "<div style='margin-left:".$i."'>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>";  // Here This is not Working
    echo "</div>";
    $i+=50;
}
?>
```